# Execute async non selectable stored procedure in EF Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, entity-framework-core-2.1

I'm trying to execute async non selectable stored procedure in EF Core 2.1.

```
  return Ok(
              await db.Set()
              .FromSql($"EXECUTE PROCEDURE MY_PROC({id})")
              .ToListAsync());
```

*Error*:

> The type arguments for method 'DbContext.Set()' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

I also tried:

```
return Ok(
             await db.MYDB
              .FromSql($"EXECUTE PROCEDURE MY_PROC({id})")              
             .ToListAsync());
```

*Error*:

> 500 (Internal Server Error) in console

Then I tried creating a static method:

```
public static async Task ExecSqlNonQuery(Entities db, string sql)
{
     using (var com = db.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
     {
         com.CommandText = sql;
         com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         db.Database.OpenConnection();
         await com.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
     };
}
....
return Ok( await ExecSqlNonQuery(db,$"EXECUTE PROCEDURE MY_PROC({id})");
```

but with this code, I get:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'object'

only works on non async and old-fashioned way:

```
public static  bool ExecSqlNonQuery(Entities db, string sql)
{
    try
    {
        using (var com = db.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
            com.CommandText = sql;
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            db.Database.OpenConnection();
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();

            return true;
        };
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
......
return Ok(ExecSqlNonQuery(db, $"EXECUTE PROCEDURE MY_PROC({id})"););
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: What is the target database type?

Comment: Firebird 2.5.thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`FromSql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsql?view=efcore-2.1) method is for record set (query) returning SQL commands. For other types of commands you should use some of the [`ExecuteSqlCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlcommand?view=efcore-2.1) or [`ExecuteSqlCommandAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlcommandasync?view=efcore-2.1) method overloads.

> Executes the given SQL against the database and returns the number of rows affected.

For instance (assuming the SQL syntax is correct):

```cs
await db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync($"EXECUTE PROCEDURE MY_PROC({id})");
return Ok();
```